# Difference between ASN and ASCII

Tags: ascii, asn.1

Please explain the difference between the ASN and ASCII formats.
What are they used for?

Answer (score 2):

See [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) and [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) at Wikipedia, the two are orthogonal concepts, one is a notation for data structures the other is a character encoding scheme.